# Is there an art to lying?

Tags: word-usage, comprehension

1.) "If you believe that deceivers are colorful folk who mislead with elaborate lies and tall tales, you are greatly mistaken."

2.) "If you yearn for power, quickly lay honesty aside, and train yourself in the art of concealing your intentions."

Hey guys, I was unable to understand what this one author meant by these quotes, even as directly stated.  I was wondering if you're able to explain.

For the first quote, does it mean that
Deceivers do not try as much when deceiving, as in telling a simple lie, Rather than taking the time and wasting their time in coming up with a perfect detailed lie? Does he intend to say that the best deceiver is the one that gets to the point and keeps things quick resulting in better success rate of his own interests? Or could it mean that the best deceivers lie by not telling the whole truth resulting in my next question..

2.) Although overall, it's a bad case to be caught lying. What do you think of not lying, yet not telling the full truth either? Is this another alternative? Is there a certain term for this?

I would appreciate some feedback.

Comment: Just a random thought, but if #1 had been “… **just** or **simply** colorful folk …” then for me it would be clear that it’s “just/simply” the author saying that such people aren’t to be viewed as “colorful folk,” but rather as something worse (evil people, perhaps ?).  Even without “just/simply,” however, I still read it like this, as if the “just/simply” are still there and “simply/just” ellipted.

Comment: Can I request that you edit the title of your question? "Is there an art to lying?" might be an interesting topic, but would be thoroughly opinion-based and therefore off-topic. I don't *think* that's what you're asking though, so it would be a good idea to clarify.

Comment: I agree, the title must be changed. It has nothing to do with what he put in his question body...

Comment: Actually, what is in my question body has very much to do with the title. The quotes are what raised the question.

Comment: I frankly can't tell what you're asking.  If there is a question there, it is exceedingly broad.

Comment: The main question was the title. Next questions were the meanings behind the first two quotes, as I was unable to fully interpret them and was asking on opinions of others.

Comment: @HotLicks He seems to be bringing up three different questions under one umbrella...

Comment: Well if the OP is confirming that the title is the question, it should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the title; yes, an art of lying exists, one of the many arts of deception. Danny addresses the title nicely.

First sentence means that deceivers are much more subtle than you think, and not like the classic ridiculous, tall-tale-telling liar.

Second sentence means that honesty and other "honorable" traits don't get you very far in a world of dirty tricks, questionable decisions, loads of big secrets, etc. and so you should learn how to play with such tricks, decisions and secrets in order to prosper.

And for

> 2.) Although overall, it's a bad case to be caught lying. What do you think of not lying, yet not telling the full truth either? Is this another alternative? Is there a certain term for this?

The term for this is **half-truth**.

Comment: Nice answer, I'll wait and see if there are more opinions, and if not, then up vote yours

Answer (score 1):

According to Sam Harris, lying is a form of deception, but not all deceptions are lies. Men deceive with Just For Men facial hair coloring. But this isn't a lie. Many deceptions are not explicit lies. Furthermore, any intent to falsify the listeners reality is a lie. I would read Sam Harris' *Lying* and Frankfurt's *On Bullshit* for an amazing treatise on lying and bullshiting.

Comment: To answer your question, there is an art to lying. But the art of deception has greater depth and dynamics.